# Angularjs - set default child view to ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I followed [this example](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/using-nested-states-angularjs-ui-router/) to set up a page with 2 child views.

I have everything in place now, and if I click on the specific link, the subviews are displayed as expected.

Here's my app.js file, in which you can see all of my states:

```
   $stateProvider.state('app',
      name: 'app'
      url: '/app'
      abstract: true
      templateUrl: './sections/menu/menu.tpl.html'
    ).state('app.home',
      name: 'home'
      url: '/home'
      templateUrl: './sections/Home/Home.tpl.html'
    ).state('app.details',
      name: 'appDetails'
      url: '/details/:zoneID'
      templateUrl: './sections/zoneDetails/zoneDetails.tpl.html'
      controller: 'currentZoneFilter'
    ).state('app.details.overview',
      name: 'appDetailsOverview'
      url: '/details/:zoneID'
      templateUrl: './sections/zoneDetails/zoneDetailsOverview.tpl.html'
    ).state('app.details.edit',
      name: 'appDetailsEdit'
      url: '/details/edit/:zoneID'
      templateUrl: './sections/zoneDetails/zoneDetailsEdit.tpl.html'
    ).state('app.setup',
      name: 'setup'
      url: '/setup'
      templateUrl: './sections/setup/setup.tpl.html'
    ).state 'app.about',
      name: 'about'
      url: '/about'
      templateUrl: './sections/about/about.tpl.html'
      controller: 'info'

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise 'app/home'
```

as you can see, I have `app.details`, `app.details.overview`, `app.details.edit`.

`app.details` is the parent, and here's the page code:

```
This it the parent page
<a ui-sref="app.details.edit">Show edit</a>
<a ui-sref="app.details.overview">Show overview</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

If I click on the link, the right template and page section is displayed. My question here is: How can I have Overview loaded by default when I reach this page?

I had a look at `$urlRouterProvider.when`, that I think that `.when` is good if you have a different URL.

My URL should be `details/:zoneID` for the page with overview template loaded and `details/edit/:zoneID` when the edit template is loaded, so I think that `.when` is not a good approach. Any help? thanks

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise ?

Comment: otherwise is used to specify the first page of the app. The otherwise should be used to go to the home page if any url state is wrong. You can see it at the end of the app.js code

Comment: ah true. try add abstract:true to your parent state, and remove url from overview state (or set it to an empty string). Check abstract state in the documentation.

Comment: I tried, but now the page is not loaded at all. I read that abstract should be used when the page should never be reached directly, but it is used as a container for other pages..the problem is that I need app.details page as well to be available, as it contains some info I need to provide regardless from the child page loaded at the bottom, so app.details need to be available to for direct access as well as the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I finally solved this.

I changed state URLs for app.details / app.details.overview / app.details.edit like this:

```
.state('app.details',
  name: 'appDetails'
  url: '/:zoneID'
  templateUrl: './sections/zoneDetails/zoneDetails.tpl.html'
  controller: 'currentZoneFilter'

.state('app.details.overview',
  name: 'appDetailsOverview'
  url: '/details'
  templateUrl: './sections/zoneDetails/zoneDetailsOverview.tpl.html'

.state('app.details.edit',
  name: 'appDetailsEdit'
  url: '/edit/day:day'
  templateUrl: './sections/zoneDetails/zoneDetailsEdit.tpl.html'
```

so that now the URL starts with the zoneID and then it appends the details or edit to display the right template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the rule function of $urlRouterProvider.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
                // check if the location is the desired location then move to the //new location.
            });
```

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.rule checks the URL, my URL should be details/:zoneID but with overview loaded. I cannot really check and match a url as it need to be the same

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple way. Check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki for implementation details.

1. Listen for the `$StateChangeStart` event. If this matches your state, perform a redirect. Be sure to execute `event.preventDefault()` to cancel current route change.
2. Add a controller to your parent state, it will check the $state.current value and if the value match his state will redirect to the child (this is what i have in my application).

EDIT : as requested in comment :

```
if($state.current.name != 'app.details'){
        $state.go('app.details.overview');
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of the second option? (tha one you have in your application) as I have already a controller in the parent that I can you, but i didn't relaly understand what you mean with checking the current state

Comment: Done this is pretty straightforward you will have to add the params for you paramatrized states though.

Comment: That didn't work. I still have my details page with no overview content loaded

Comment: Do I still need to have abstract and no URL on overview as you said before for this to work?

Comment: No need of abstract, however since overview is a child of the 1st one, the URL you add in overview will be added to parent's URL. So if you want to be the same, remove URL in child state.

Comment: Ok, so, removed URL from app.details.overview, removed abstract from app.details, added your bit of code in the controller but still nothing. When app.details is loaded with url app/details/4 (4 is the zone ID, for example), I can see the top section (app.details), but app.details.overview is still not there. If I want to display it, I need to click on the link